# Structure to add a node id with correct type

Tags: c, embedded, structure

I am trying to specify a node id on my server but don't understand the structure that I am supposed to follow. I followed the seemingly simple structure to change the node ID and didn't receive errors or warnings. I was successful in creating the nodes as seen below but not creating a node_id. I thought to add a simple node id I would follow the same structure and add the lines with $$$$ in them;

```
// opcua_server.c

#include "ua_types.h"
#define HANDLE_PDU1 15

const uint8_t EN_DISPLAYNAME_PDU1[] = "PDU1";
const UA_UTF8_string_t ENGLISH_TEXT[] = {
    {0, 0}, {sizeof(EN_DISPLAYNAME_PDU1) - 1, EN_DISPLAYNAME_PDU1}};

void opcua_add_nodes(void) {
    UA_Status_t status = 0;

    // Add PDU1 Folder
    UA_Folder_t PDU1;
    UAServer_Init_config_structure_Folder(&PDU1);
    PDU1.node_handle = HANDLE_PDU1;
    PDU1.display_name_handle = HANDLE_PDU1;
    UA_NodeId_Config_t randomHANDLE; // $$$$ Not creating node id
    PDU1.node_id = randomHANDLE;     // $$$$ Not creating node id

    status = UAServer_Create_Folder(&PDU1);
    if (status != 0) {
        UA_SERVER_PRINTF("UAServer_Create_Folder returned: %d\n",
                         (uint16_t)status);
    }
    status = UAServer_Add_to_folder(folder.node_handle, PDU1.node_handle);
    if (status != 0) {
        UA_SERVER_PRINTF("UAServer_Add_to_objects_folder returned: %d\n",
                         (uint16_t)status);
    }
}

// ua_types.h
typedef struct {
    /**
     * A mandatory unique identifier that identifies the node in the library.
     * The value zero is invalid.
     */
    uint32_t node_handle;
    /**
     * A mandatory unique identifier that allows the host to efficiently look up
     * the
     * node name text to display in a translate callback. The value zero is
     * invalid.
     */
    uint32_t display_name_handle;
    /**
     * An optional unique identifier that allows the host to efficiently look up
     * the
     * node description text to display in a translate callback. The value zero
     * is
     * invalid.
     */
    uint32_t description_handle;
    /**
     * An optional visibility mask that restricts the visibility of the node
     * depending
     * on which user is logged in. The anonymous user is bit 0 and bits 1 - 15
     * represent the corresponding users
     */
    uint16_t user_visibility;
    /**
     * Specifies the namespace index for this node. The UA namespace is 0 and
     * cannot
     * be used. The default server namespace is 1. Other namespaces may be added
     * to the configuration data structure.
     */
    uint16_t namespace_index;
    /**
     * An optional parameter set that defines the NodeId for the node as a
     * string
     * or a GUID. If this parameter is set to default values then the SDK will
     * assign
     * an opaque node id to the node. Opaque node ids are easily decoded by the
     * SDK
     * and offer the best performance. Only populate this parameter set if your
     * application requires it.
     */
    UA_NodeId_Config_t node_id;
} UA_Base_t;

/*****************************************************************************/
/** \brief A configuration structure for Folder address space nodes.
 *
 */
typedef UA_Base_t UA_Folder_t;

/*****************************************************************************/
/** \brief A configuration structure for View address space nodes.
 *
*/
typedef UA_Folder_t UA_View_t;

/*****************************************************************************/
/** \brief A configuration structure for Method address space nodes.
 *
 */
typedef struct {
    /**
     * Configuration common to all nodes
     */
    UA_Base_t base_config;
    /**
     * The file size in bytes
     */
    uint64_t size;
    /**
     * The file is writable
     */
    bool_t writable;
    /**
     * An optional writable mask that restricts write access of the file
     * depending
     * on which user is logged in. The anonymous user is bit 0 and bits 1 - 15
     * represent the corresponding users
     */
    uint16_t user_writable;
} UA_File_t;
```

[image: UA_NodeId_Config_t Struct Reference]

[image: Wrong node_id displaying]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to specify the identifier type (which I did by looking at the identifier types) and set it equal to opcua_node_encoding_string. The result is a string node id that I set out to create.

```
    //Add PDU1 Folder
    UA_Folder_t PDU1;
    UAServer_Init_config_structure_Folder(&PDU1);

    PDU1.node_handle             = HANDLE_PDU1;
    PDU1.display_name_handle     = HANDLE_PDU1;
    PDU1.node_id.identifier_type = opcua_node_encoding_string;

    const char TEST_STRING_ID2[]          = "PDU1";
    PDU1.node_id.string_identifier.length = sizeof(TEST_STRING_ID2) - 1;
    PDU1.node_id.string_identifier.data   = (uint8_t*)TEST_STRING_ID2;

    status = UAServer_Create_Folder(&PDU1);
    if (status != 0)
    {
        UA_SERVER_PRINTF("UAServer_Create_Folder returned: %d\n",        (uint16_t)status);
    }
    status = UAServer_Add_to_folder(folder.node_handle, PDU1.node_handle);
    if (status != 0)
    {
        UA_SERVER_PRINTF("UAServer_Add_to_objects_folder returned: %d\n", (uint16_t)status);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define `PDU1`, a `node_id` is already created and associated with it. You just need to access `node_id` and assign value for each of its elements.

Replace

```
UA_NodeId_Config_t randomHANDLE; // $$$$ Not creating node id
PDU1.node_id = randomHANDLE;     // $$$$ Not creating node id
```

with

```
PDU1.node_id.identifier_type = xxxx;  // xxxx, yyyy, zzz is whatever valid value for their type.
PDU1.node_id.string_identifier = yyyy; 
PDU1.node_id.guid_identifier = zzzz;
```